# Redefine protected abstract method as private

Tags: delphi, oop

I have an abstract class in which in the protected section an abstract method is declared.
Can I in its child redefine this method as private?

It looks logically - in abstract class this method shall be protected to be avaible to children 
(and only to children);
but in the child this method can be private, it (method) don't call outside of objects of this class.

Can I make so?

Comment: A slightly different solution that's less elegant but doesn't rely on arcane knowledge of the compiler might be to split the method in two - give the protected one an awful name to warn potential callers and provide access to it through a little wrapper method with the "normal" name.

Comment: Addition: Instead of naming the protected method ugly mark it `deprecated`. Surround the one call site that's allowed (i.e. in the private wrapper) with `{$WARN SYMBOL_DEPRECATED OFF}`/`{$WARN SYMBOL_DEPRECATED ON}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed do that.

```
type
  TMyAbstractBase = class
  protected
    procedure Foo; virtual; abstract;
  public
    procedure DoFoo;
  end;

  TMyDerived = class(TMyAbstractBase)
  private
    procedure Foo; override;
  end;

procedure TMyAbstractBase.DoFoo;
begin
  Foo;
end;

procedure TMyDerived.Foo;
begin
  Writeln('TMyDerived.Foo');
end;
```

Then the following code, located in a different unit of course, does not compile:

```
var
  obj: TMyDerived;
....
obj.Foo;//[dcc32 Error]: E2361 Cannot access private symbol TMyDerived.Foo
```

It's not a good idea to do this though. Now consider this class, again declared in a different unit.

```
type
  TMyDerived2 = class(TMyDerived)
  public
    procedure Foo; override;
  end;

procedure TMyDerived2.Foo;
begin
  inherited;//this does nothing
  Writeln('TMyDerived2.Foo');
end;
```

If `TMyDerived2.Foo` ever executes, then the `inherited` statement does nothing. That's because `TMyDerived.Foo` is private.

So, my advice is that whilst what you propose is possible, that you do not do it. As a rule of thumb you should avoid reducing the visibility of members.

Comment: "Located in a different unit" is a key statement here which may not be completely obvious to a beginner

Comment: why not make it `strict private` instead of comments ?

Comment: what about `TMyAbstractBase(obj).Foo` or `(obj as TMyAbstractBase).Foo` ?  Looks like compiler bug. If you want to make a method final sealed - then just mark it so.

Comment: Thank You. And I understand why "located in a different unit".

Comment: Make it `strict private`, then the need for a *different* unit goes away.

Comment: Doesn't redeclaring Foo as private in TMyDerived produce a compiler hint or warning "method had lower visibility than in ancestor" (or some such)?

Comment: @Marjan Yes it does just that